# Gradle war static content dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have next modules dependency:

static content(war) -> spring core + admin ui (war app) -> user ui app (war app)

And I don't know best way to use static content in both dependent projects
I tried something like:

```
war {
    from (project(":static-resources").fileTree("src/main/resources")) {
            into('/WEB-INF/classes')
    }
   from (project(":static-resources").fileTree("src/main/webapp/js")) {
       into('/js')
   }
   from (project(":static-resources").fileTree("src/main/webapp/resources")) {
        into('/resources')
   }
}
```

But all this work fine for 'spring core + admin ui app', for user ui app I need to include static content resources + spring core resources which is not good for maintenance

Any suggestion?